# Get IIS Log data in C# module

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am writing the `.Net Module` for **IIS** to get the log details before or after **IIS** has been written log file .As per `MSDN documentation`

```
HttpApplication.LogRequest Event Occurs just before ASP.NET performs any logging for the current in LogRequest handler request.
```

So, how can get the log data which looks something like below:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.0

#Version: 1.0

#Date: 2014-11-27 10:42:57

#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus  sc-win32-status time-taken

2014-11-27 10:42:57 ::1 GET / - 29897 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/39.0.2171.71+Safari/537.36- 200 0 0 42905
```

Comment: Do you want access to the log textfile stream, or just the same data contained in the logfile?

Comment: I don't want access to log file just get same data that going to write in log file by IIS in .Net module

Comment: The info in the log entry comes from the `HttpContext` object, so in your case, simply set a breakpoint and analyze what you can dig out from that object.

Comment: yes info in log entry available in `HttpContext` but i don't know what details user configured to log , so without knowing knowledge about details to be logged i need to get log data . so i should get the log details in `HttpModule`

Comment: Is it possible to read IIS log data in current context ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No , I cannot get the IIS log data in HttpModule i need to write custom HttpModule and make  log data in the same as IIS log data looks like . but i cannot get the following fields  time taken , byte sent, receive, and win32 status code in custom HttpModule.